# How do i automatically add the h1 of a page to an ahref link on that page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The site that i am working on has an 'Apply For This Job' button the a href on the button is as follows `example.com/?Question12=insert%20job%20you%20are%20interested%20in`

what we want is for `example.com/?Question12=insert%20job%20you%20are%20interested%20in` to be automatically be pulled in from the h1 on the page.

For example if the job page was for a Web Developer the h1 would be `<h1> Web Developer </h1>` and the link would automatically be `/?Question12=web%developer`

I'm sure this is easily done through javascript/jquery or php any help would be greatly apprecated.

Thanks in advance

- We want a link on the page to automatically have what ever is written in a h1 tag at the top of the page added to the end of the link.

Comment: Add some code please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is getting downvotes because it doesn't really fit the model for good questions here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and familiarise yourself with the way we work here and try editing your question to better fit the guidelines on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved like this:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8pLovpdm/1/)

HTML

```
<h1>Web Developer</h1>
<a href="example.com/?Question12=">job link</a>
```

JQUERY

```
var link = $("a").attr("href");

link = link+$("h1").html();

link = link.replace(/\s/g,"%20");

$('a').attr("href", link);
```

Comment: Thats almost it but the link doesn't have the h1 added on the end?

Comment: actually you're right, forgot to add the link to the <a> element, my bad lol.

Comment: check the updated version

Comment: Hey thanks thats solved it perfectly. This is just a little extra if i needed to pull say a h2 in after the h1 as a second query  is that possible?

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/8pLovpdm/2/

Comment: one last thing sorry, this has now applied to ever a href on the site is there a way to limit it to just the one?  e.g all of the menu items now have the code after them ?

Comment: you must give the job link a class so that will be the only affected link... here: https://jsfiddle.net/8pLovpdm/3/